# Find duplicates in a column

Tags: excel, vba

The below code counts the duplicates in a given column and gives the count of same but i need if there is/are any duplicates mention "Duplicate found" in subsequent cell for example if values are same in cell F3, F4 and F15 (required Blank column that is column "G" is already present as i am validating column "F") then it should be sorted and in cell G3, G4 and G15 "Duplicate found" should be there.

```
Dim helperCol As Range
Dim count As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set helperCol = .UsedRange.Resize(, 1).Offset(, .UsedRange.Columns.count)
    With .Range("F1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 6).End(xlUp))
        helperCol.Value = .Value
        helperCol.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        count = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count - helperCol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count
    End With
    helperCol.ClearContents
End With

If count >= 1 Then
    Range(count, "G") =   " Duplicate/s found"
End If
```

[image]

output should look like :- (Bold font is done by me only just for clear understanding its not required )

[image]

Comment: Try like this `Range("G" & count) ` instead of `Range(count, "G")`. And mention what is your error and where do you get it.

Comment: Range("G" & count) its not giving any kind of error but not any output as well.

Comment: @JonSmith - The description you give of what you need and the code you provided are doing two entirely different things. Do you want "Duplicate Found" to be listed **after** the duplicates are removed? Before and after pictures would be very helpful in this case.

Comment: Use `Cells(count, "G")` (recommended) or `Cells(count, 7)` or `Range("G" & count)` (not recommended) but never `Range(count, "G")`.

Comment: Tigregalis i tried your suggestions too  here code runs with no error but no output :-(

Comment: Put `Debug.Print count` before `If count >= 1 Then`; what happens?

Comment: Still same code runs but no output

Comment: What appears in the Immediate window? `count` should have a value

Comment: Here count is the number of duplicates not the address of cell having error, this is the issue this  code is not working i guess right ?

Comment: Show us your sample input data, and sample output data; so that we know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: here u go :-   https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKwi9.png

Comment: and i updated image in my question too

Comment: For clear understandings i made the duplicates bold

Comment: @ Scott Holtzman  well i don't want to remove duplicates i just want to print "Duplicate found" in very subsequent cell. and i have attached an image too. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @JonSmith - That is what I thought you wanted. Your code does something **very different**. Is a formula solution okay? There is no need for VBA for this?

Comment: here is output :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKwi9.png

Comment: @ Scott Holtzman this is a part of my big code and if we use formula or function i think it will be a bit tricky to connect the rest of the code right ?

Comment: @ Scott Holtzman  it will be great if i could get a code instead of formula

Comment: Sorry this is output :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGKGM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will produce "Duplicate Found" in the cell 1 across to the right (i.e. column "G") of any cells in column "F" with duplicates.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim CEL As Range, RANG As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ' Build a range (RANG) between cell F2 and the last cell in column F
        Set RANG = Range(.Cells(2, "F"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))

    End With

    ' For each cell (CEL) in this range (RANG)
    For Each CEL In RANG

        ' If the count of CEL in RANG is greater than 1, then set the value of the cell 1 across to the right of CEL (i.e. column G) as "Duplicate Found"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RANG, CEL.Value) > 1 Then CEL.Offset(, 1).Value = "Duplicate Found"

    Next CEL

End Sub
```

Another option is to use a Dictionary (first add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime), which stores unique values and their ranges. As you progress down the range, you fill up the Dictionary, and if a value already exists, then for the original range and all subsequent occurrences, record "Duplicate found".

Tools > References

[image]

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim CEL As Range, RANG As Range
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ' Build a range (RANG) between cell F2 and the last cell in column F
        Set RANG = Range(.Cells(2, "F"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))

    End With

    ' For each cell (CEL) in this range (RANG)
    For Each CEL In RANG

        If CEL.Value <> "" Then ' ignore blank cells

            If Not dict.Exists(CEL.Value) Then ' if the value hasn't been seen yet
                dict.Add CEL.Value, CEL ' add the value and first-occurrence-of-value-cell to the dictionary
            Else ' if the value has already been seen
                CEL.Offset(, 1).Value = "Duplicate Found" ' set the value of the cell 1 across to the right of CEL (i.e. column G) as "Duplicate Found"
                dict(CEL.Value).Offset(, 1).Value = "Duplicate Found" ' set the value of the cell 1 across to the right of first-occurrence-of-value-cell (i.e. column G) as "Duplicate Found"
            End If

        End If

    Next CEL

    Set dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

In theory, this should be faster as it does less iterations over the entire range; `Countif` function checks entire range for matches with each cell, i.e. 1 million cells x 1 million cells. But I'm unsure how expensive the `Dictionary` object is. For this method, the Dictionary object grows as you check each cell, so subsequent accesses *might* become slower, but this should still be less expensive than checking every cell again; additionally, the Dictionary object can only grow as large as the number of unique values.

For other performance increases:

1. Set at the start of the code:

   ```
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlManual
   ```
2. Restore at the end of the code:

   ```
   Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Scripting.Dictionary method works great.

Answer (score 0):

This code will produce "Duplicate Found".

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

   Dim LastRow As Long
   LastRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   .Range("G2:G" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(RC[-1]:R[" & LastRow - 2 & "]C[-1],RC[-1])>1,""Duplicate Found"","""")"

End With


End Sub
```

For sorting, try this on your own, and come back with question if you cannot figure out how that code works. Questions should be kept to a single issue on SO.

Comment: it works absolutely great but takes a significant time, is there any way to decrease this time as i have this kind of data in millions.

Comment: @JonSmith - 'data in millions` - that would have been good to know upfront :)

Comment: if Tigre answer above is too slow or doesn't work, let me know. I have another idea then his.

Comment: If your 'data [is] in millions', maybe you should consider using a database? Excel is gonna have a hard time dealing with that much data no matter what you're using

Answer (score 0):

**Fast search**

Use data field arrays instead of range loops, a clever nested search method and e.g. the dictionary method to speed up the search. I added a `Timer`to check the time needed (n times faster than other examples):

**Code**

```
Public Sub FindDups()
' Site:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47099413/find-duplicates-in-a-column
' Purpose: mark duplicates via Array

Dim t        As Double              ' Timer
Dim v      ' As Variant             ' one based 2dim array, variant
Dim ws       As Worksheet           ' worksheet
Dim i        As Long                ' item counter
Dim j        As Long                ' item counter
Dim n        As Long                ' last row number
Dim d        As Object              ' dictionary, late binding
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
' stop watch
  t = Timer
' set worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' get last row number in column F
  n = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  ReDim v2(1 To n - 1, 1 To 1)
' create one based 2dim data field array
  v = ws.Range("F2:F" & n).Value2
' check for duplicates
  For i = 1 To n - 1
    If d.Exists(v(i, 1)) Then
             v2(i, 1) = " Duplicate/s found"
    Else
      For j = i + 1 To n - 1            ' start search for dups one row below
          If v(i, 1) = v(j, 1) Then
             v2(i, 1) = " Duplicate/s found"
             d(v(i, 1)) = v(i, 1)       ' add to dictionary
             Exit For
          End If
      Next j
    End If
  Next i
' write values back
  ws.Range("G2:G" & n).Value2 = v2
  Set d = Nothing
' Time needed
  MsgBox "Time needed: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.00 ") & " seconds."

End Sub
```